# How to switch "controlgroup" background color

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I want to change the background color for each single button in my "controlgroup". I know how to change the background color if the button is not pressed: (This first piece of css works!)

```
.ui-page-theme-a .ui-btn.ui-btn{
    background-color: #123456;
}
```

But the following code is not working to change the color if the button is active:

```
.ui-page-theme-a .ui-btn.ui-btn-active{
    background-color: #123456;
}
```

And here is my complete html code:

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta name=viewport content="user-scalable=no,width=device-width" />
    <link href="css/colorpicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/colorpicker.js"></script>
    <script>
        onStart();
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="preview" class="preview"></div>
        <p id="output"></p>

        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
            <legend>Horizontal controlgroup, checkbox:</legend>
            <input type="checkbox" id="modul1">
            <label for="modul1">Modul 1</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="modul2">
            <label for="modul2">Modul 2</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="modul3">
            <label for="modul3">Modul 3</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="modul4">
            <label for="modul4">Modul 4</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="modul5">
            <label for="modul5">Modul 5</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="modul6">
            <label for="modul6">Modul 6</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="modul7">
            <label for="modul7">Modul 7</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="modul8">
            <label for="modul8">Modul 8</label>
        </fieldset>

        <div class="colorpicker" style="display:none">
            <canvas id="picker" var="2" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is a live code for you: http://jsfiddle.net/DCtEF/

Comment: Your CSS doesn't match the HTML output.  None of your HTML has a class of "ui-btn", or "ui-btn-active".

Comment: actually these classes exist, i think jquery generates them... like I said the first piece of code is working

Comment: Gotcha... - for the future, can you please edit your HTML input with a copy paste from the page source of the page?  Copying from page source will include any jquery generated classes.

Comment: Added the complete html for you, as far as I know jquery enhances the html code dynamically while its loading the page, so I can't show you more code.

Comment: Hmmm...  Last request - is there a live link of this site I can visit so I can get on it with chrome dev tools?  Kind of hard to see what all is going on without it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DCtEF/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thunder, your fix is really simple, there are two possible ways to fix the issue, one (the second option) is probably more desirable.

The real problem here is linking priority.  This style sheet: `"http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css"` is what is over-riding **YOUR** styles.  Probably you have your own style sheet linked in the head, then this one beneath it.

---

The quick and easy way is to simply add `!important` at the end of the css property.
http://jsfiddle.net/SaDrZ/

```
background-color: orange !important;
```

This can be kind of nasty, it's generally best practice to avoid using !important whenever possible.

---

The more desirable way is to simply make sure you are linking the above stylesheet **BEFORE** your own stylesheet. Like below...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyles.css" />
```

Comment: Dev tools is a savior for things like this.  By inspecting the element, you can quickly see that the default style applied by the jquery mobile CSS file was overriding your own custom styling.  From there it's easy to diagnose how to fix once you know the real problem.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

I havent checked your code But I'd check this first: `.ui-page-theme-a .ui-btn.ui-btn-active`  -active is not a css selector for active behavior. consider `.ui-page-theme-a .ui-btn.ui-btn:active`

Comment: Why would it be .ui-btn.ui-btn???  The fact that the two classes are butting up against each other indicates they are two classes applied to the same element.  .ui-btn-active therefore is a separate class and not a typo for a pseudo-selector.

Comment: I'Ve already tried that, it's working for the time you hold the mouse button down. But it's not the matching css statement for the "activated?" state of the button.

Comment: Well, I can't see the classes used. No css was provided to check against. The only thing I was able to provide guidance with is that he may have produced a typo. But if you already tried that and it didn't fix it, then provide the css or a fiddle so We can have a better ground to work with

Comment: Yeah - :active does not do quite what some may initially think it is used for.

Comment: Well, actually it work in specificity. If he was using a framework such as Bootstrap, the :active selector would automatically give the btn used an active response